# Why didn't Cora's kiss break the Dark one's magic

Tags: once-upon-a-time

In the whole tv series we are always told that `true loves kiss` breaks all magic. Now in one flash back in fairytale land we see that Rumplestiltskin and Cora had somewhat of an affair and Rumple taught her how to use magic. He fell in love with Cora and she fell in love with him.

She explicitly states that she removed her heart because it was stopping her because she loved him.

My question is why is that their kissing did not break the Dark One's magic but Bell's kiss was breaking it? Both were true love's kisses why would one work and the other would not?

Also please use spoiler tags if you are going to refer to a specific episode or specific moment

Comment: Are you sure that Rumple said he loved her? Or that if it he did, he actually meant it? He's a trickster; it's in his nature to manipulate those around him (as illustrated by the current arc). I haven't seen those episodes, so I'm not going to offer this as an answer, but I'm guessing if you watch them carefully, the Dark One is somehow playing Cora to get what he wants (perhaps the curse?)

Comment: When Rumple is dying he asks Cora if she ever loved him in a way that shows that he loved her. She replies yes, that is why I removed my heart. Through the dying moments of Rumple (who ends up not dead) needs verification if she loved him shows to me that he loved her

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dark One's magic is connected through his dagger not through him.  When an object is the one causing the magic then the object would need to be removed or destroyed.

For example:

> When Ariel got the bracelet from Regina/Ursala, she got legs and only when it was removed did she get her tail back.

Comment: 1. There is a spoiler tag you can use. Type >! before your spoiler stuff.
2. But when bell kissed Rumple his dark magic started to fade away. Which was another true love's kiss

Comment: Then what you think about Bell's kiss?

Answer (score 1):

There are different levels of love in the Once-verse. You can be in love with someone, and vice versa, without them being a TRUE love. True love, in Once Upon a Time, is a very rare, soul-mate level connection (when it comes to romantic love). True love is deep, powerful, and most importantly unselfish. The writers/producers were asked in the podcast on The Miller's Daughter whether or not Rumple and/or Cora were playing the other, and they said no, the two genuinely loved each other. The difference between Rumple/Cora and Rumple/Belle though, is that although Cora *did* love Rumple, she wanted power/revenge more than she loved him, so it wasn't true love and thus her kiss didn't threaten the Dark One curse. Belle IS his true love, and so her kiss started to break the curse.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because Cora never saw that part of him as a curse but rather as one of the reasons she loved him. Unlike Belle, who always wanted him to change that dark part of himself. This is only my opinion of course.

Comment: Maybe, but still, "true love's kiss breaks all curses"